# Prove that, $\zeta(3)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}H_n^{\phi(2)}(2n+1)}{n(n+1)}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, zeta-functions

$$\zeta(3)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}H_n^{\phi(2)}(2n+1)}{n(n+1)}$$
Where, $H_n^{\phi(x)}$, is the n-th Harmonic number of the alternating-zeta series $\phi(x)$. Here in this case;

$$H_n^{\phi(2)}=1-\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}-...\pm\frac{1}{n^2}$$

Comment: I’m pretty sure that’s not true as stated.

Comment: The LHS is more than 1, the RHS is less than 1.

Comment: If, instead of the alternating zeta series, you just use the zeta series, and you take out the $(-1)^{n+1}$, then I think you get a true identity but that doesn’t quite seem like what you want.

Comment: Can you show how, I plugged this onto my program, it gives around $1.20197..$ for $10^3$ terms and as this converges much slower than the actual $\sum(1/n^3)$

Comment: @Robo300, I'm all up for knowing, elaborate?

Comment: No problem man, happens all the time

Comment: Okay, now that I’ve actually figured out how to read it, I’m pretty sure it’s true, but I’m running short on time to actually prove it. Try writing out the terms of the alternating series in successive rows, it gives a good intuition for why it should be true.

Answer (score 0):

To actually put what I commented into an answer, probably the best way to see why this sum converges, is to expand out the summands for the Harmonic numbers in rows:
$$\frac {3}{2}(1)$$
$$-\frac {5}{6}(1-\frac {1}{4})$$
$$+\frac {7}{12}(1-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9})$$
...
Now, instead of computing the sum in rows, we look at the sums of the columns.in the column of ones, we find
$$1(\frac{3}{2}-\frac {5}{6}+\frac {7}{12}...\frac {2n+1}{n(n+1)}...)$$
A little tinkering with these numbers reveals that this is in fact equal to 
$$1((1+\frac{1}{2})-(\frac {1}{2}+\frac {1}{3})+(\frac {1}{3} + \frac{1}{4})...(\frac {1}{n} + \frac {1}{n+1})...)$$
The nth partial sum here is $1+\frac {1}{n+1}$, which tends to one as n goes to infinity, so the coefficient of one in this sum.
When we expand the column with fourths, a similar analysis reveals that the total coefficient on one fourth is one half. And in general the coefficient on $\frac 1{n^2}$ is 1/n. So adding all these together, the summands are $\frac {1}{n^3} $, giving the normal sum for $\zeta (3)$.